# Activiti - How to get a custom form type to hold multiple values?

Tags: java, jsp, activiti

I'm having trouble getting my head around custom form types. I want to create a form type that stores multiple values i.e. basically acts like an enum. It only needs to be different in name for rendering purposes.

I made this class:

```
import org.activiti.engine.form.AbstractFormType;

public class ImpactedSitesFormType  extends AbstractFormType {

         public static final String TYPE_NAME = "impactedSite";

         public String getName() {
           return TYPE_NAME;
         }

         public Object convertFormValueToModelValue(String propertyValue) {
           Integer impactedSite = Integer.valueOf(propertyValue);
           return impactedSite;
         }

         public String convertModelValueToFormValue(Object modelValue) {
           if (modelValue == null) {
             return null;
           }
           return modelValue.toString();

         }

       }
```

And I added this to my activiti.cfg.xml:

```
<property name="customFormTypes">
            <list>
                <bean class="ImpactedSitesFormType"/>
            </list>
</property>
```

I'm making a webapp and I can get the name and id of the form type back but the values return null even though I gave it values in Activiti designer. I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: Also I'm creating the forms myself dynamically in the jsp.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have with the Community Edition form renderers is that the form renderer doesnt have access to the execution (or task) context. The only runtime data available is the variable that is bound into the form element.
This makes it hard to handle any sort of complex form control (and is likely why Alfresco have turned their back on form properties approach in their enterprise edition).
I created a simple enum based on a variable list in community but it was a hack. I set the variable to a CSV (e.g. bill, ted, geno, sally) created a custom renderer that turned this into a pulldown an then bound the selected result back into the same variable.
This is really the only approach you can use if you use the default form renderers.
If you want to do any sort of non trivial form, you will need to use an external rendering engine.